# Difference between self.instanceVar = X and instanceVar = X in Obj-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For the following two lines in an obj-c class:

```
self.instanceVar = X
instanceVar = X
```

Is the only difference that the 'self' version calls the synthesized 'setter', whereas the latter simply sets the instanceVar and doesn't go through the setter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the following:

```
@property( retain ) NSString * myprop;
```

If you set it by `self.myprop`, the NSString instance will be retained.

If you set directly the instance variable, this will not be the case.

So always use the `self.`, unless you're absolutely sure...

Comment: Thanks for the advice - so basically, always use 'self'. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Although always using self isn't wrong per se, you do need to be aware of the performance hit which can be significant if you are accessing a lot of primitive types (int/float/bool etc) in a loop. You can argue this until the cows come home, but in general I would access primitive types from within the class without using self. Any other objects it's good to use self unless you are sure about what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The implication of this is that the synthesized getter will wrap additional code depending on how the property is specified - so use of assign / retain / copy along with nonatomic / atomic change the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent question and understanding the difference between setting a variable through its accessor rather than directly assigning it is very important.

Here's what happens: when you declare a `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *variable` in the header, you add a property to your object. Simple enough. Calling `@synthesize` does the following thing: it generates two methods in your class, `setVariable:` and `getVariable`. Of course, if you name your property "name", the methods will be `setName:` and `getName`.

Now, it is important for you to understand what happens in the `setVariable:` method. The method is declared something like this:

```
- (void)setVariable:(NSString *)theVariable {
    if (variable != nil) {
        [variable release];
    }

    // variable is the class member, 
    // theVariable is the object that was sent by the method parameter
    variable = [theVariable retain];
}
```

When you call `self.variable = @"test";` you will actually call `[self setVariable:@"test"]` which is exactly the method that was generated by the `@synthesize` call!

When you call `variable = @"test";` you do just that - you assign a string to a variable, without retaining it or anything.

If you were to call `self.variable = nil` the current value of the variable would be released and variable will be assigned to `nil`, but if you were to call `variable = nil` you would just ditch the reference to the previously assigned value (object). Therefore, if you would be calling

```
self.variable = @"test";
// wrong, do not do this in this case
variable = nil;
```

you would be be generating a memory leak because the @"test" object that was assigned to variable and retained through its accessor is never going to be released. Why's that? Because the setter (setVariable:) never gets called to know to release the previously held value.

For the sake of example, here's what `getVariable` looks like:

```
- (void)getVariable {
    // variable is the class member
    return variable;
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. **self.instanceVar** accesses the value through the property.

Although it is not necessarily the synthesized property. You can write your own get and set methods that can be called.