# About calling my properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between self.instanceVar = X and instanceVar = X in Obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484945/difference-between-self-instancevar-x-and-instancevar-x-in-obj-c)

```
@interface Whatever : Something
{
  DPad *dPad;
}

@property (retain) DPad *dPad;

@end
```

And then I synthesize:

```
@synthesize dPad;
```

I noticed I can all my dPad with

```
self.dPad
```

and just

```
dPad
```

Is there any difference? I can use any? If I used both for whatever reason, both would affect the same object, right?

Comment: Yes there's a difference.  Use the Search box in the top right of the page to find any of the dozen answers that have been posted for this question before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference. self.dPad calls the getter method for dPad, whereas dPad just accesses the instance variable directly. If you override the getter, any additional checking or setup, or memory management you might do in the getter will not be called. As a good practice, it's probably better to call the getter, than access directly, even if you're just synthesizing and not overriding.

Comment: So as a good practice I shall always use self.dPad then?

Comment: Unless you explicitly wish to bypass the getter for some reason, I would.

Comment: @Omega: Usually yes. There is some controversy around using accessors in `-init` and `-dealloc`. Mike Ash has written about it on his blog: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html

Answer (score 1):

One accesses the property directly, the other uses the accessors.

Directly accessing an instance variable was possible long before Apple invented the dot-syntax for properties.

`self.dPad` get rewritten transparently by the compiler:

```
self.dPad = someOtherDPad;
[self setDPad:someOtherDPad];

// or for getters

[self.dPad doSomething];
[[self getDPad] doSomething];
```

Using the properties and the accessors allows for more flexibility, for example Key-Value-Observing is only possible using the accessors. The downside is a small loss of performance, which you shouldn't notice in most cases.