# difference between self.myivar and self->myivar in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Hi I know that when accessing members in C using the arrow notation (`->`) makes elminates the need for using both star and dot (`* .`) every time an object needs to be accessed.

But in Objective-C is there any difference between `self.myivar` and `self->myivar`? I have noticed that both of them work in my case, where I have an myivar declared as a property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between self.instanceVar = X and instanceVar = X in Obj-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484945/difference-between-self-instancevar-x-and-instancevar-x-in-obj-c)

Comment: `self.myivar` is a method call, `self->myivar` is not.

Comment: so self.myivar only works if a setter is declared by user or @property?

Comment: Not really, settings works if there is a method `-setMyivar:`. Whether it is declared as a `@property` or not doesn't make a difference. Or method `-myivar` when you are reading.

Comment: So it wont work unless there is a setter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between self.ivar and ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4142177/), [Difference between self and normal variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/536388/), [Properties and accessors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6085080/), [Ivar property, access via self?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4088801/), [When to access properties with self](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4271657/), [What is the (style) difference between “self.foo” and “foo” when using synthesized getters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3494157/), and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+self.ivar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But in Objective-C is there any difference between self.myivar and self->myivar?

Yes, there's a difference. Assuming that `foo` is a pointer to an object:

`foo->bar` is equivalent to `(*foo).bar` where the dot indicates the member access operator to get the instance variable `bar`.

`foo.bar` is equivalent to `[foo bar]`; that is, it sends the message `-bar` to the object pointed to by `foo`. That may just return whatever is in `foo`'s `bar` instance variable, but it may do other things. There may not even be an instance variable named `bar`. As long as there's a method called `-bar`, however, `foo.bar` is valid. There should also be a `-setBar:` method if you're using `foo.bar` as the left hand side of an assignment, like: `foo.bar = baz;`.

Note that although `self` is a keyword in Objective-C, it always acts as a pointer to an object. There's nothing special about `self` with respect to accessing properties or instance variables. I've used `foo` as the name of the object pointer above to demonstrate that property/ivar access works the same way for any object pointer, but you could substitute `self` for `foo` above.

Comment: Note that using `foo->bar` quite effectively breaks encapsulation.  It also bypasses KVO.  Don't do that.